# Kleopatra GPG4win fails to publish key on server

Tags: gpg4win, kleopatra

I am new to PGP and wanted to test it. I have successfully created a keypair and wanted to publish on the server, but get the following error:

The output from C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe was: gpg: sending key 2C0731CF036975A9 to hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net gpg: keyserver send failed: Server indicated a failure gpg: keyserver send failed: Server indicated a failure

Not sure what is going on. I am using the defaulted keyserver, but have also tried changing and adding from the keyserver pool list, but no success.

I am sure I am doing something wrong, but what?

One piece of possible interest: this is my second attempt, as the previous one failed...but i used obviously the same name and email, but i do not remember if i successfully published the first failed attempt....

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The web-ot-trust approach is dead since an [attack in mid 2019](https://coinspice.io/news/openpgp-spam-attack-poisoned-certs-already-on-sks-keyserver-network/). The keyservers went down / do no longer accept new keys and signatures.

But do not get me wrong, this does not mean that PGP/GnuPG is broken or dead! Thinks just got a bit more complicated: In order to use PGP you have to exchange keys out of band and verify them manually. E.g. you could publish your keys on your (TLS protected) homepage, like I did [here](https://dirdi.name/files/mail_dirdi_name_pub.asc).